# Mime type error when adding a CSS file to Angular

Tags: css, angular, mime-types

I'm trying to build a static site using Angular. What I want is to have some global css/js/image files to be added to the `index.html`

This is my code in `index.html`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layers.css">
```

My `css` folder in in the same level as the `index.html` file

I'm getting this error for each stylesheet I added (from ng serve with chrome)

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/layers.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I've tried adding this too

```
#.angular-cli.json
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "css/layers.css"
      ],
```

How can I fix this?

My angular setup is

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.5
Node: 8.1.4
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.5
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: you should be adding the relative path `"./css/layers.css"`

Comment: mmm.. double check the path of your styles... remeber angular.cli json file start from src folder ..

Comment: Can you load the stylesheet into your browser by typing http://localhost:4200/css/layers.css into the location bar? And if that works, what does the browser report the MIME type to be?

Comment: hey @Aravind, tried `./css..` and the same issue . @Mr Lister, I cannot access the css directly. Maybe its not loading due to this MIME type issue ?

Comment: @sameera207 What do you mean, you cannot access the css directly? Do you get a 404 error? If so, that might well be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @sameera207 Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 18):

## Solution 1 (with Bootstrap installed)

All you need to do is:

1. Go to .angular-cli.json under the root directory of your angular app.
2. Modify the styles array to include bootstrap before styles.css

```
    "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

**Note**: the path to bootstrap is relative to `/src/index.html` that's why you need `"../"` before `node_modules`.

3. Exit the current session of ng serve and start it again.

Here is an [Awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYPyy-hvjYc&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXwcl3a6rIfAI7QmGYIkfK5&index=1#t=05m18s)

## Solution 2 (with Bootstrap referenced)

All you need to do is:

1. Go to styles.css under the root directory of your angular app.
2. Add this line at the top:

```
@import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Here is [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-an-initial-html-form-template)

Answer (score 13):

If you already have the styles.css in angularcli.json or angular.json, you don't need it in index.html. The cli will inject the contents automatically. So remove that line from the index.html and everything should work.

Answer (score 13):

For someone who will face same problem.

The usual reason for this error message is when the browser tries to load that resource, the server returns an HTML page instead. For example, if your router catches unknown paths and displays a default page without a `404 error.` Of course that means the path does not return the expected `CSS file / image / icon /` whatever... [ref from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668792/7680307)

Lets assume we have `Angular 6` project with a file structure like this:

```
project
    |-src
      |-app
      |-assets
      |-environments 
      |----
```

lets assume we need to put a `theming` folder (that contains css files) directly inside src folder.

```
project
    |-src
      |-app
      |-assets
      |-environments
      |-vendor // Theming
         |-theme-light.css
          |theme-dark.css
```

if we tried to access that theme file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href: '../vendor/theme-dark.css'>
```

an error will be thrown.

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/vendor/theme-dark.css' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
>   checking is enabled.

If we paste that url in the browser, it will not give the plain css file because the path is wrong.

**Solution**

So What you need to do is find the correct path. (*we can find out by past that `url` in
   the browse and see what will returned*)

In whis case putting `../src/` reference will fix the error

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href: '../src/vendor/theme-dark.css'>
```

**Note:** The exact path and router configuration depends on how you have setup your project and the libraries you are using with Angular.

Comment: Thank you! This was a problem we hit after we made changes to our webpack config.

Answer (score 11):

@sameera207 Answers in comments are correct, relative path must work, I too had same issue and answers of comments are working for me. I tried to reproduce your error, I made css folder at level of index.html and added css file then added path in styles array.

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "./css/my-styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/css/tether.min.css"
  ],
```

then **restarted server**, I mean performed `ng serve` again and its working. Make sure you have done it and **restared server** and if still problem persists please let me know, I would be glad to help you.Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try by adding

```
<base href="/">
```

at top of all styles in `index.html`;
it works for me

Comment: By default it's added in index.html file

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I have installed material-icons using `npm i -S material-icons` from the terminal.

I have followed the instructions given in the npm package installation and have placed a link in the index.html like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=<node_module_path/material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css>`

It has thrown a `its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

You have to actually paste the path mentioned in href in `angular.json` file under `styles` array

Don't forget to restart the angular server, you can thank me later

FYI: Angular - V8.x, material-icons - V0.3.1

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got the same type of error in my angular project. After adding this `type="text/html"` piece of code the error is gone.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="filename.css">
```

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me. i would still like to know why it worked though, because it was complaining about MIME type to be `('text/html')` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

(*Note: regarding asp.net boilerplate zero (paid version) but could be your solution also *)

Yes, @Franklin, strange though for a paid app making me repeatedly look like a forgetful old man. ;-) But might be system related.

I did found:
[support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/7742/Refused-to-apply-style-from-](https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions/7742/Refused-to-apply-style-from-%27URL%27-because-its-MIME-type-%27texthtml%27-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-MIME-type-and-strict-MIME-checking-is-enabled#answer-c620c30c-9df3-c49b-dfb1-39f083974d40) :

"run >> ***gulp build*** << command on terminal and recreate minified files"

worked for me. (again ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

in your angular.json, add the config option

> "extractCss": false,

like this

```
"options": {
        
        "aot": true,
        "outputPath": "dist",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "extractCss": false,
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code which links your layers.css file.

> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layers.css">`

From this line please remove `type="text/css"`.

So, the code will become:

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layers.css">`

Use this line, I hope It will work now. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

make new CSS folder inside the assets folder then put your CSS file inside CSS then link again with the new location

```
Eg : -  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/materialize.min.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run an angular code by asp.net zero using ng serve and faced this issue.

Normally all angular project run with the command ng serve. But the asp.net zero framework initially minifies the css file and then do the ng serve process..these 2 things are integrated in the command npm start. If atleast once npm start is done, the minified files are stored in our local... So next time onwards even if you do ng serve , it would be working..

So running `npm start` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had that issue because I have defined the same *.css file,
in both the *.html & the angular.json files
on angular

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from **index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layers.css">
```

and then go to angular.json (since angular 5) or angular-cli.json depend on your version. set the path to your css files in the styles array like below

```
"styles": [
          "src/style1.css",
          "src/style2.css"
        ],
```

finally, restart the app. **ng serve**

Answer (score 0):

Check the name file and path is right, in my case in angular I had under the array css

```
src/styles.css
```

And in the index.html file I added by mistake this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="style.css">
```

The **style.css** not exists in my case but **styles.ccs** yes.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Update your angular.json with the below details.

```
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
        ]
```

Step 2:
Make sure the index.html DONT have the "css" and "js" imports/references.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, it will solve it just by moving them from the node_modules folder to the assert folder.
For example...

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="assets/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/styles.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD `<base href="/">`
at top of all styles in `index.html`; Works for me

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap CDN then you have to import it to src/styles.css files as below

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

the bootstrap version can be changed so you can use the version as yours.