# unable to load the css file in angular 6 application

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to add basic reset styles in my angular 6 application.
But i keep getting following error in console.

**

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:4200/app/style-components/reset.css' because its
>   MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
>   strict MIME checking is enabled.

**

As you can see my css files name is reset.css and i am using following line in index.html to add this file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>EasyNotes</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/style-components/reset.css">**
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to this new version of angular and its quite a blocker for me.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mime type error when adding a CSS file to Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521971/mime-type-error-when-adding-a-css-file-to-angular)

Comment: do you see your style sheet when you go http://localhost:4200/app/style-components/reset.css ?

Comment: Try navigating to http://localhost:4200/app/style-components/reset.css and see what it contains. Probably the server isn't serving the right file

Comment: Here's the good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668792/7680307) similar problem like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the file is not found at runtime, so an Html error page (or similar) is returned. Put the file into the `assets` folder and reference it like:

```
href="assets/reset.css"
```

To check this, open your browser and access your page, press `F12`, click `Network` and press `F5` to reload. Have a look at the files Http status.

You may also put it somewhere else and reference it in the `angular.json` file, in the `styles` section and remove it from `index.html`:

```
"styles": [
   "src/app/style-components/reset.css"
],
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan ..it worked after putting it inside the asset folder. But what i am not understanding is why it was giving an error while putting the file inside the src/app and referencing it from there

Answer (score 1):

Here's the good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668792/7680307) on similar problem like yours.

The usual reason for this error message is that when the browser tries to load that resource, the server returns an HTML page instead, for example if your router catches unknown paths and displays a default page without a 404 error. Of course that means the path does not return the expected CSS file / image / icon / whatever...

The solution is to find the correct path and router configuration so that you get your plain CSS file / image / etc. when accessing that path.