# why the css is not applied with tarteaucitron?

Tags: css, json, angular

I'm working on an angular project, for which I'm trying to apply a certain css that was provided to me. This css is provided with the js file, `tarteaucitron.js`

So I've added the `tarteaucitron.css` in my `angular.json` in the `styles` part

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
          "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
          "src/assets/tarteaucitron/css/tarteaucitron.css",   // this is where I added the css           
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Yet I'm having this error in my chrome debugging console

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/css/tarteaucitron.css?v=20181023' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Can anyone explain, please?

Update

---

I've used the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49269425/2572645) but to no avail and no, the solution I received is closed to my problem but the solution is not working in my case.

Comment: Have you tried visiting that URL in the error? The most common cause of that error is that the server is returning something like a 404 page.

Comment: Hi @DBS, yes. I'm redirected to `localhost:4200`

Comment: @AndyK Your browser's network tab in the developers tools displays the complete headers returned by the server. Check the mime type there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lengthy discussion, it seems that the culprit is the `tarteaucitron.js` file.

It contains this part

```
// Step 1: load css
if ( !tarteaucitron.parameters.useExternalCss ) {
    linkElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkElement.type = 'text/css';
    linkElement.href = cdn + 'src/assets/tarteaucitron/css/tarteaucitron.css?v=' + tarteaucitron.version;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkElement);
}
```

Commenting that part makes the css script readable.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the library and putting it into a vendor file (which is ALWAYS minified without comments)

Answer (score 1):

Make a vendor file in assets folder and paste your css into vendor file and give path of your css file into index.html file.